# How to get rid of boundary 'seams' in surface plots?

Tags: plotting

I'm plotting Richmond's minimal surface, and I get this annoying boundary 'seam' in the central disk at the 10 o'clock position. Any ideas about how to get rid of it?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Code used:

```
Richmond[n_, z_] := {
  -1/(2 z) - z^(2 n + 1)/(4 n + 2), 
  -I/(2 z) + I z^(2 n + 1)/(4 n + 2), 
  z^n/n
};

richmond =  ParametricPlot3D[
  Re[Richmond[5, r Exp[I theta]]], {r, 0.5, 1.16}, {theta, 0, 2 Pi},
  Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
  Background -> Black, Mesh -> {16, 128}, 
  MeshStyle -> {{Thick, White}, {Thick, White}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.5], FaceForm[Green, Blue]}, 
  BoundaryStyle -> {Tube[.01], Yellow}, PlotPoints -> {100, 100}
]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's a boundary, unfortunately `BoundaryStyle` does not allow to set it for each parameter separately.

You can leave automatic styling of the boundary in the main plot (so we won't have a gap in place of this yellow line) and add fancy boundary, only for `r`, in separate plot:

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[
  Re[Richmond[5, r Exp[I theta]]], {r, 0.5, 1.16}, {theta, 0, 2 Pi},
  Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, Background -> Black, Mesh -> {16, 128}, 
  PlotPoints -> {100, 100}, MeshStyle -> {{Thick, White}, {Thick, White}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.5], FaceForm[Green, Blue]}, BoundaryStyle -> {Thick, White}]
 ,
 ParametricPlot3D[
   Re[Richmond[5, # Exp[I theta]]] & /@ {.5, 1.16}, {theta, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Yellow, Tube[.01]]
 ]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Many, many thanks! Works like a charm.